# How to put img properly in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
.item:nth-child(1)
.item:nth-child(2)
.item:nth-child(3)
```

are crumbled when i put image.

you can see what`s going on at http://dainielhhong.com/page1.html

```css
 .container{
          display: flex;
          margin: auto;
          margin-top: 2vh;
          height: 88vh;
          width: 67vw;
          border-top: 2px black solid;
          border-left: 2px black solid;
          border-right: 2px black solid;
      }
    .item:nth-child(1){
      flex: 1;
      height: 28vh;
      border-right: 2px black solid;
      border-bottom: 2px black solid;
      font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;

    }
    .item:nth-child(2){
      flex: 2.6;
      height: 28vh;
      border-bottom: 2px black solid;
      font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;

    }
    .item:nth-child(3){
      flex: 1;
      height: 28vh;
      border-left: 2px black solid;
      border-bottom: 2px black solid;
      font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;

    }
```

```html
<div class = "container">
     <div class = "item">
     </div>
     <div class = "item">
     </div>
     <div class = "item">
     </div>
     <img src="crack.svg">
     </div>
```

I want to make image to not crumble item:nth-child(1)(2)(3).

What should I do?

Comment: do you want the img inside `nth-child(3)`?

Comment: no. I want another box. You can see <img src="crack.svg"> in html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put the image below the flex items, wrap your `.container` inside a parent container, and put the image in there. Currently, flex will squeeze the image in the same row as the items.

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <img src="crack.svg">
</div>
```

Now, style the `.parent-container` like your `.container`, and change to container to just `display: flex`.

Now if I had to guess, you want to use the SVG as a separator. For that, also add `img { width: 100%; }` and remove the fixed `height: 88vh` from your `.parent-container`.

The result will be:

[image: Final result]

Answer (score 0):

You can set `flex-basis` with the percentage for each item, make the first 3 100% in total and add

```
flex-wrap: wrap
```

to the container. Also note I added

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to each item, so the percentage will include the border size.

or any value that will fit the ratio you need

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  height: 88vh;
  width: 67vw;
  border-top: 2px black solid;
  border-left: 2px black solid;
  border-right: 2px black solid;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  flex-basis: 22%;
  height: 28vh;
  border-right: 2px black solid;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  flex-basis: 56%;
  height: 28vh;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 22%;
  height: 28vh;
  border-left: 2px black solid;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container img{
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/AFb.svg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is 3 ways to position image

The 2 first ways are to change html because you use `flex`

The last is to position the img

```css
 .container{
          display: flex;
          margin: auto;
          margin-top: 2vh;
          height: 88vh;
          width: 67vw;
          border-top: 2px black solid;
          border-left: 2px black solid;
          border-right: 2px black solid;
          position: relative;
      }
      .img{
       position: absolute;
       right: 99px;
      }
    .item:nth-child(1){
      flex: 1;
      height: 28vh;
      border-right: 2px black solid;
      border-bottom: 2px black solid;
      font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;

    }
    .item:nth-child(2){
      flex: 2.6;
      height: 28vh;
      border-bottom: 2px black solid;
      font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;

    }
    .item:nth-child(3){
      flex: 1;
      height: 28vh;
      border-left: 2px black solid;
      border-bottom: 2px black solid;
      font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;

    }
```

```html
<h1>image after container</h1>
<div class = "container">
     <div class = "item">
     </div>
     <div class = "item">
     </div>
     <div class = "item">
     </div>
</div>
<img src="crack.svg"> 

<h1>image inside nth-child(3)</h1>
<div class = "container">
     <div class = "item">
     </div>
     <div class = "item">
     </div>
     <div class = "item">
     <img src="crack.svg">
     </div>
</div>
 
<h1>image inside nth-child(3) with css and not change html</h1>
<div class = "container">
     <div class = "item">
     </div>
     <div class = "item">
     </div>
     <div class = "item">
     </div>
     <img src="crack.svg" class="img">
</div>
```